# LINQ Intersection not working

Tags: c#, linq

I have two list that i want to compare. In one i have a small amount of objects and in the other im sure i have the objects from the first list plus others.

Im trying to do an intersection to get the objects from the second list that are in my first list.To do that i have the object inside the two list is of type

```
    public class ReportDataImportant : ReportData
{
    public String IdTitular { get; set; }
    public String Identificacion { get; set; }
    public String IndicadorPersona { get; set; }
    public String Titular { get; set; }
    public decimal Porcentaje { get; set; }
    public int Cotitulares { get; set; }
    public String IndicadorNacionalidad { get; set; }
    public String Nacionalidad { get; set; }
}
```

I have also a comparer class like this:

> ```
> public class ReportDataComparer : IEqualityComparer<ReportDataImportant>
> {
>     public bool Equals(ReportDataImportant x, ReportDataImportant y)
>     {
>         if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, y)) return true;
>         if (Object.ReferenceEquals(x, null) ||
>         Object.ReferenceEquals(y, null))
>             return false;
>         return x.Identificacion.Equals(y.Identificacion);
>     }
> ```

```
    public int GetHashCode(ReportDataImportant obj)
    {
        if (Object.ReferenceEquals(obj, null)) return 0;

        return obj.Identificacion.GetHashCode();
    }
}
```

An to make the intersection i call it with this expresion :

```
var reult = _list1.Intersect(List2, new ReportDataComparer()).ToList();
```

However im not getting the result im expecting. Does somebody know what is happening?

Comment: Are you sure `x.Identificacion.Equals(y.Identificacion);` works properly?

Comment: Please provide more details about the result that you expect and its differences from the result that you get (instances that shouldn't be there are returned, or instances that should be there are missing).

Comment: @AlexSikilinda this Equals is a string.Equals(string) method so i assumed it works properly.

Comment: @dasblinkenlight I'm getting a subset smaller than the one I was expecting there are lof of instances missing.

Weird behavoir when i call Except() method it makes inersection .

Comment: What isn't working properly @Jose? Based on `x.Identificacion.Equals(y.Identificacion)` it appears that the way the objects are being compared on the basis of the value of `Identificacion`. So if two instances of `ReportDataImportant` have all differing properties except `Identificacion` then they _will_ be considered as equal. Also do note that `.Equals` is case-sensitive.

Comment: @degant Exactly two instance of ReportDataImportant with same identificacion are the same object, basically is the same object in 2 diferent moments of time the only value that change is "Porcentaje" 
I added x.Identificacion.ToUpper().Equals(y.Identificacion.ToUpper()); on the Equals method to be sure that this is not the problem and im getting the same result 

I should  get the same number of objects from list 1 in list 2 cause i know that all the objects from list1 are in list 2 but im getting less objects tha expected

Comment: How about sharing what objects aren't intersecting? Or construct a small example on dotnetfiddle?

Comment: @degant https://dotnetfiddle.net/YgkNQ9 dont know really how to use detnetfiddle but if u put it in aconsole application im specting a result of "2" in the console cause there are 2 objects that are the same (according to my ReportDataComparer )